# Difference between $\mathbb{C}^\times$ and $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm asked a question where it says: Consider the transformation $f: \mathbb{C}^\times \to \mathbb{C}^\times$. How does the set $\mathbb{C}^\times$ differ from $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Usually, $\Bbb C^\times$ indicates the multiplicative group $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thank you so much! I'm just a bit confused about why the zero must be removed to form a multiplicative group...

Comment: $0$ has no multiplicative inverse.  All other complex numbers have a multiplicative inverse.

Answer (score 4):

When $R$ is a ring, we denote its invertible elements by $R^\times$ which reduces to $R\backslash \{0\}$ when $R$ is a field. This is exactly the case for $\Bbb C$ so $\Bbb C^\times = \Bbb C\backslash \{0\}$.